# MVC image display works with Azure URL but not CNAME

Tags: iis, model-view-controller

So, this works if accessed via myazureproj.azurewebsites.net but NOT if I get there via a CNAME www.mydomain.com pointed to azurewebsites.

```
<p>
    <a href="http://www.smartwool.com/">
        <img border="0" alt="Smartwool " src="/Ads/smartwool.png">
    </a>
</p>
```

File is local to the iis. All I found here was about things that weren't? Trying to display ads for an event-in-progress so it'd be swell to find a quick fix.

Comment: Have you told your Azure website to respond to this domain (and are paying for it)?

Comment: Another reason... Do you have an ad blocker installed? It's likely blocking that image as it contains "ads".

Comment: Yes; using myproj.azurewebsites.net and myproj.mydomain.net work fine for regular views and such; this page displays either way, but only includes the image if I use the azurewebsites.net URL. No AdBlocker, it's a clean copy of FF with nothing installed.

Comment: Are you getting  404 for the image?

Comment: No. If you View Source and copy the URL into a new tab, the image displays. There's something in MVC/IIS that's stopping it based on the difference in URL. Just haven't been able to figure out what.

Comment: how about a 404 for your CSS or Javascript then? Any errors in the console? It may be easier to give us the actual URL.